# How to setup database for iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I'm currently working on making an iOS app where the user have to either login og create an account (and afterwards login). For that i need to somehow connect to a database. The database is of the type SQL and created with phpmyadmin in XAMPP. For now it only consist of one table called 'user' with the the attributes 'id', 'email' and 'password'. I've created two PHP script called signin.php and signup.php and placed the in the c:\xampp\htdoc directory so i can load the script through localhost. Here are the script for signup:

```
<?php

$email = $_GET['email'];
$password1 = $_GET['password1'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","<mypassword>","app_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

To create a new account you write the following your browser:
http://localhost/signup.php?email=youremail@something.com.dk&password=123456

My question is, if this is the proper way to it? I'm really having a hard time google the right thing because i dont know what to search for. I would really appreciate your help and do tell me if the listed information isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all:

You "have" to use https not http or you customers passwords will fly through the internet without any protection.

Also:
Currently your user can do SQL injections on you server. Use this code:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$email,$password); // the variables are of type string->s and they are ordered in the way the questionmarks are in the query!
    $stmt->execute();
    $affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if($affected_rows == 1)
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
}
```

Also probably you shouldn't echo the response out in 'plain test' but return something machine readable like json so your app can display usefull results to the user.

Comment: Thanks for tip and the code. Im still a bit unsure if using this method with php is the optimal way of doing it. I really want to do it the "rigth" way from the beginning.

Comment: There is no 'right way' that works best for every single iOS&android application. It is especially important what developers in your company know. If you have php guys this is the right way. One thing to note: you would usually not even send the real password the user has typed into your textfield but hash it directly and only transfer the hash since nobody should ever see (not even you) what the actual user password is. This way - if you get hacked - you will never leak any user passwords!

Comment: Yeah i figured that. Some friend told me to use md 5 algorithm to  hash the password.

Comment: Since you are using php you should use the native hashing api:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php